# How to make a cronjob type plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cron

Hi i am new on wordpress and has been given a task to make such a script that will fetch posts by categories and shoot email to subscribers.

The table structure for subscriber is below

```
Subscriber Id - primary key
Subscriber email - varchar
Category Id - int
```

Now the task is to fetch post for last week for each category that exists in above table an send a newsletter to the respective subscribers each monday automatically.

I have an idea how to fetch post i will probably do it with get_post() method but i'm not sure how will i do it. Should i made a plugin? If yes, then can a plugin file be run like a cronjob ? Or if there is any other good approach please advice .

Thanks
Raheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make a plugin. Following is the way to add cron job functionality in WordPress plugin. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

However, please note that this does not provide a real (system based) cron. It requires at least someone to visit your site, so that the functions keep on executing periodically.

Comment: In fact, you can even use an action hook like 'init' instead of using a cron job and then put a condition in your function to check if it is Monday, then make an entry in database (if today's entry is already made then skip), so the check will be performed on every visit and thus faster.

Comment: thanks, i was reading this... as i said i want it every monday 12:00 am. So how a site visit affect my event ?

Comment: Nice way around sir. I keep this init approach for safe side :)

Comment: but still if no one visit site on monday :\

Comment: The entry within one day or in some hours is possible, even if there is single visit on your site. However, entry at exact time like 12:00 am is hardly possible without a system(real) cron. The WP cron will require to get executed at least by a single visit and it will schedule your event and then after its expiration another visit will be required.

Comment: See if you can make use of this filter http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_schedules or you can do something like this - schedule the event on weekly basis and for first time visit exactly 12:00 am on Monday. But, still I would say that system cron is anyway more accurate than this.

Comment: Can you take the relevant parts out of those links and put them in your answer? If those URLs change this answer becomes useless

Answer (score 1):

WordPress already has a cron style mechanism, [`wp_cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron)

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_task_hook' );
}

add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );

function my_task_function() {
    // do something 
}
```

Ofcourse, what you do when the cron job fires is up to you. Your stated use for this is off topic here.

### A sidenote

WP Cron is checked when a user visits your site. If you have a 5 minute cron job, but nobody visits for 2 hours, that's 2 hours during which nothing happens. It also executes after 5 minutes, not on 5 minutes. So if it has been 5 or more minutes since the last time it ran, it will run. Because of this, do not expect it to run at 1:00 on the dot.

This is because WordPress is ran on a wide variety of systems, and there's no reliable 100% automatic way to schedule a cron job from PHP on all environments.

You can make wp-cron faster and reliable however by having an actual cronjob ping `/wp-cron.php`

Comment: Tom is this possible that i make a plugin file and point my ssh or cpanel to run that particular file ? will wordpress code work in perfect way like we usually run php scripts other than any cms ?

Comment: If you point it at wp-cron.php it will run the 'perfect' way you expect so long as you call it at the same frequency. Calling a file inside your plugin from CPanel is a security risk, bad practice, and encourages sloppy coding, and would execute even if your plugin was disabled. I ***STRONGLY*** recommend against it. I also suspect you're making the same make in these other CMS', e.g. Drupal has a similar system to WordPress https://www.drupal.org/cron